# How to use a variable in perl as an input to a pipe command?

Tags: perl, shell

example:

```
foreach $gid (sort (keys %list)){
    if ($list{$gid} >= $count){
        print "$list{$gid} ---> ";
        print "$gid ---> ";
        system(getent group | grep -w ^$gid | awk -F: '{printf $0 } ');
    }
}
```

**here `$gid` is the variable that contains a value that i want to search within a system commmand and get the first part of that command printed.

Comment: The main problem is why you use `system()` when you can do all with perl?

Comment: I did'nt  know that pearl can be used directly. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to shell out here. It looks like you want the group name from the group ID. Perl's built-in [getgrgid()](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/functions/getgrgid.html) function can easily handle that by passing in the GID:

```
for my $gid (sort (keys %list)){
    if ($list{$gid} >= $count){
        print "$list{$gid} ---> ";
        print "$gid ---> ";
        my $name = getgrgid($gid); # <-- here
        print "** $name **\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: this is working fine! but there is another issue. There may be 2 groups with the same GID , the difference between them is that one group has the last column empty and the other one has atleast one member. This command pulls out the null record. How can i check for a non-null member group?

Comment: Re "*There may be 2 groups with the same GID*", No, group ids are unique.

Comment: % getent group | grep -w 22
voice:x:22:
grad:*:22:abrun

Comment: here voice and grad are two groups with 22 as GID.

Comment: @AnirudhAV, files on the operating system are associated with a group by GID number, not by a name. Thus, if you have two names mapped to the same GID, it's impossible to tell which of the groups owns a file. Thus, that's a serious bug in system configuration: In effect, if both groups are recognized, they'll *both* own any resources owned by either, because what you have is just one group called by two names.

Comment: @Anirudh AV, No, there's still only one group: `22`. You just have a badly corrupted definition of that group. Trying to give a single group two names and two membership lists (as you have) makes no sense! That's simply not going to work. Fix your `/etc/group` file!!!

Answer (score 3):

Rather then trying to build a proper shell command containing a proper regular expression, it's simpler to use the provided C library calls.

It's unclear what you want. `$gid` sounds like you have a group's id, but `^$gid` makes it look like you have a group's name. As such, I provided two answers.

---

If you have a group's name and you want its id,

```
my $name = 'root';

while ( my ($this_name, $this_id) = ( getgrent() )[0,2] ) {
   if ($this_name eq $name) {
      print("$this_id\n");
      last;
   }
}
```

---

If you have a group's id and you want its name,

```
my $id = 0;

my $name = getgrgid($id);
print("$name\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

`system` takes a string, so just use interpolation as elsewhere.

```
system("getent group | grep -w ^$gid | awk -f: '{printf \$0}'");
```

(You need to escape the `$` in the `awk` command to prevent Perl from expanding `$0` before passing the string to `system`.)

Comment: Not exactly the safest approach, though. It'd be better to pass the arguments through the environment and let the shell interpret them, or as explicit strings passed to the shell's argv, to avoid potential for shell injection attacks should a malicious key be present in the list.

Comment: You can validate `$gid` before passing, though; in this case you would just need to verify that it is a valid group name.

Comment: If your code will only ever be run on a system that doesn't allow more group names than POSIX requires be valid, sure. On cygwin, however, usernames or group names with spaces (f'rinstance) are things that happen in practice.